Cascade Segmentation - Are the channels set up correctly?
I want to train a machine learning model for fine masked details in 2D DICOM images. I have 500 images ready for labeling/annotating. Can I use this technique or have I misunderstood?
Annotation of fish + spine


I annotate 500 images with 1 class: fish. Then I train a model1.pth which segments the fish from the background. The model has 2 out_channels: fish and background.

I annotate the same 500 images again, but now with 2 classes: fish+spine. I load model1.pth and make a model with 2 in_channels and 3 out_channels: spine, fish and background and save the model as model2.pth

Finally, I annote the 500 images all over again, but now I include the deformations. If I have e.g. 3 types of deformations, each of them gets their own class. I load model2.pth, make a model with 3 in_channels and 6 out_channels: background, fish, spine, deform1, deform2, deform3 and save the model as model3.pth.

The model is now ready for being used directly on new images. Is this how it works?


Background and details. What I have tried
The goal is to locate deformations in the spine of fish. So far I have tried to segment 3 classes + background by ising an UNet model from MONAI. The images are 2D DICOM images transformed to NifTi format (.dcm.nii.gz) and of typical size 2000x900 pixels. I have used 3Dslicer for the annotation. The classes (so far):

Background

Fish

Spine

Deformation


I have tested on (only) 12 training images so far, just in order to get it running, I get a result with all 3 classes, but I guess the model got overtrained. Furthermore, I guess this technique makes it harder to make small changes after the training session is finished. E.g. I want to have many different types of deformations.
My results: left of the red line: from tensorboard, Right of the red line: testing of the model on new iamge

Before I start to annotate 500 images I want get it verfied that I am on the right path. I hope that by using the cascade technique, I can get a model which segments the fish and the spine easily and that I can experiment with different annotations of deformations afterward.

this might be a better fit for the [stats.se] SE. you're asking about concepts of ML, not specific implementation/programming issues.

your approach doesn't sound outlandish to me. have you tried training the model, or are you asking for people to bet on the outcome? a dozen images might not be enough, or maybe the model is underpowered, or you missed some data augmentation. the segmentation you're getting looks like the receptive field is too small, or it's doing something stupid like tiled inference (which is a poor imitation of actual convolution), where the model can't see the whole picture, just a small shred of it, and it can't tell there's a fish.

You were right, Christoph. The receptive field was the problem. It was way too small. The accuracy increased to 75% just by increasing the area. Learning bit by bit. And that was with only 20 images. Thank you!

that sounds promising!
